# Custom Regular Expression Attribute in C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I set a customized regular expression attribute. I get always the errpr message, in this case test 123. The valid characters would be ABC for the name instead of ABC1 or ABC13 ...

```
[Test(ErrorMessage="test 123")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

My Attribute Class is:

```
public class TestAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
public TestAttribute() : base(GetRegex())
{  }

private static string GetRegex()
{
return @"[123]$";
}
}
```

why is it not working?

I am using MVC 4 with Visual Studio 2010 and Framework 4

Just to be clear. in all the cases I see in the summaryvalidation the message test123 when I save the form

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: What do you want to allow and what do you want to reject ? In other words, what is your regular expression supposed to match ?

Comment: The error message is when I set in the name something ABC, ABC12,... Appears in the ValidationSummary "test 123". "test 123" should appears only in the cases with numbers like ABC12 ABC1. I want to reject 1 2 3. My regular expression is [123]$

Comment: So it can't end in 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: @david the way it's currently set-up, you're **only** allowing regexes that contain 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: any 1 2 3 anywhere of the string, the expression is right because I tested in online, but using the code of c# of customized attributes is not working

Comment: You are still not clear on what you want ? Do you want to allow all strings except those which end in `1`, `2` or `3` ?

Comment: I am clear I need alphabetic characters and numbers from 4 to 9 including 0 snifferAnd I tested ithe expression in a web page and it is working. I used to test http://rubular.com/, if you test you will see the web mark you all the matched characters

Answer (score 0):

The following regex string will make `IsValid` return `false` for a string containing a 1, 2, or 3 anywhere in the string:

```
@"[^123]*"
```

E.g.

```
var r = new RegularExpressionAttribute(@"[^123]*");
Console.WriteLine(r.IsValid("ABC3DEF")); // false
Console.WriteLine(r.IsValid("ABC4DEF")); // true
Console.WriteLine(r.IsValid("ABC")); // true
Console.WriteLine(r.IsValid("ABC1")); // false
Console.WriteLine(r.IsValid("ABC123")); // false
```

Unlike some regex matches, [`RegularExpressionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) appears to check if the regex provided matches the **entire** string, not just a part. This is why what you see when testing a pattern on [rubular](http://rubular.com/) can be different than what you see here. It's like it automatically puts the `^` and `$` around your pattern. E.g. this returns the same values `r.IsValid` does for the inputs in my example:

```
Regex.IsMatch("ABC3DEF", @"^[^123]*$");
```

Comment: @david I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work using it in your `TestAttribute` in MVC4. Just put that pattern into your `GetRegex()` method.

Comment: Tim was set Test in as an example but I needed in a particular caracaters which I go to find in database for this reason I use TestAttribute

Comment: tim thanks it is working I changed in TestAttrinute with your regular expression and it is working now. Now I have to change only the characters I need for 123 whcih I get from database.